# Xamarin forms Unable to unable to to get file location

Tags: file, xamarin, camera

I have to open the camera and take a picture but I can't make it work. I searched similar posts but I can't figure it out. Any advice?

Manifest

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
              android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" 
              android:exported="false" 
              android:grantUriPermissions="true">

      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
                 android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

file_paths

```
<external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
<external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
<external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.plugin.mediatest/files/Pictures" />
```

Code

```
await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported && !CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Message", "Unavailable", "OK");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    Directory = "Images",
                    Name = DateTime.Now +".jpg",
                    SaveToAlbum = false
                });
                await DisplayAlert("FilePath", file.Path, "OK");
                PhotoImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                {
                    var stream = file.GetStream();
                    return stream;
                });
```

Comment: "can't make it work" is not a good description of your problem.  What is it doing or not doing?  Do you get error messages or exceptions?

Comment: Sorry for that. I mean that when i click the button it goes into break mode and the error is unable to find file location

Comment: then it's throwing an unhandled exception - you need to tell use exactly what the exception is

Comment: System.ArgumentException: Unable to get file location. This most likely means that the file provider information is not set in your Android Manifest file. Please check documentation on how to set this up in your project.

Comment: does file_paths.xml have the correct build action and content as shown in the documentation?  You did not post the complete file so I can't tell.

Comment: I think so I also added another line for testing but nothing changes  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
  <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
  <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.plugin.mediatest/files/Pictures" />
</paths>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this **[Usage](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#usage)** , and there is [a sample](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin.git) on GitHub .

```
takePhoto.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
{
    await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
    {
        DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
        return;
    }

    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
    {
        Directory = "Sample",
        Name = "test.jpg"
    });

    if (file == null)
        return;

    await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

    image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {
        var stream = file.GetStream();
        return stream;
    }); 
};
```

About [Android Misc Setup](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#android-misc-setup) ,

By default, the library adds `android.hardware.camera` and `android.hardware.camera.autofocus` to your apps manifest as optional features. It is your responsbility to check whether your device supports the hardware before using it. If instead you'd like Google Play to filter out devices without the required hardware, add the following to your **AssemblyInfo.cs** file in your Android project:

```
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera", Required = true)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera.autofocus", Required = true)]
```

You must also add a few additional configuration files to adhere to the new strict mode:

1.) Add the following to your `AndroidManifest.xml` inside the  tags:

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
          android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" 
          android:exported="false" 
          android:grantUriPermissions="true">

      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
                     android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

2.) Add a new folder called **xml** into your Resources folder and add a new XML file called `file_paths.xml`. Make sure that this XML file has a Build Action of: `AndroidResource`.

Add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
    <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
</paths>
```

Final effect :

[image]

==================================Update=====================================

After checking shared sample , there are two problems.

**First** , you'd better update Nuget Package(`Xamarin Forms 3.1`) of Solution to the latest version (`Xamarin Forms 4.3`).

[image]
[image]

[image]

**Second** , you forgot to add Provider to `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.companyname.fileprovider.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/files_paths"></meta-data>
 </provider>
```

**Note**: The part parameter(`android:resource`) inside of the provider need to be modified to your customed name(`@xml/files_paths`) in poject . You named it not `@xml/file_paths` , then it can not find provider .

Sample effect:

[image]

Comment: I have done that as you can see in the post. It gets the exception in this part:var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    Directory = "Sample",
                    Name = DateTime.Now +".jpg",
                });

Comment: @mario Okey , could you share your sample link here about this function , I will check it in my local project .

Comment: https://github.com/marioskan/MobTech.Mobile here is the github link

Comment: @mario Thanks for sharing . I have updated answer , u can have a look.